# git push origin master, is showing nothings in the bitbucket repository

Tags: django, git, bitbucket, git-bash

I'm trying to push my project for the first time in bitbucket, when I type git push origin master, as i choose master for my branch, it's shows nothing in the repository I have created in bitbucket.

the messages throws at me:

```
* [new branch]      master -> master
```

when I type git push origin master --force

the message:

```
 git push origin master --force
 Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin youruser@yourserver.com:/path/to/my_project.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: git push origin master --force solve the problem, but the source code are there only in the commit not on the source

Comment: Hello @AdamuAbdulkarim try to remove cache run this command ``git rm -rf --cached .``

Comment: Error unknown option 'chached'

Comment: @AdamuAbdulkarim: compare `cached` and `chached`. How many letters are there in the first word? How many are there in the second? (Not that `git rm -rf --cached .` is a sensible thing to do here, but it seems odd that you didn't look for your own typos.)